# Terminate After in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the intention to use the [Terminate After](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-search-terminate-after.html#java-search-terminate-after) feature of elasticsearch in order to reduce the result set.

The question is, the documents retrieved when using Terminate After, are ranked among the complete set of documents, or just among the reduced returned set?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Terminate after limits the number of search hits per shard so any document that may have had a hit later could also have had a higher ranking(higher score) than highest ranked document returned since the score used for ranking is independent of the other hits.

So yes the document will be ranked depending upon only the result set returned, but this would not affect how the actual score was calculated which takes into account all the documents.

Wanting a reduced result set and wanting it to be ranked depending on all the hits that may have occurred is a contradiction in itself.
Terminate after is generally used for filter type queries where the score of all returned docs is the same so that ranking doesn't matter.
For match type queries ES uses pagination so it's already quite efficient and you don't really need to restrict the document set anyways.

Comment: There is bit of confusion in the answer. So, if the scoring is not affected by terminate after and if results are sorted per shard, then how can we have results with higher raking "later" in the results per shard. ??

Comment: @RohitWagh scoring is not affected in the sense that the score of each document that matches the search query is indpendent of any other match that might occur later. Result will be sorted per shard but the result set will only contain the first `n` matches, so it is possible that the search query could have had another match with higher score after the search was terminated.